# Getting wrong information from github payload

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to pull the committer's email address from the payload but the payload is showing some default value like
"`noreply@server_ip`"

I am trying to parse the committer's email address from the payload but the payload is delivering like this below :

```
"author": {
        "name": "XYZ",
        "email": "XYZ@abc.com",
        "username": "xyz"
      },
      "committer": {
        "name": "GitHub Enterprise",
        "email": "noreply@server_ip"
```

The jenkins pipeline is showing like this

```
"fullName":"noreply"},"authorEmail":"noreply@server_ip"
```

My code is

```
authemail = parsedJson.changeSets.items.authorEmail[0]
```

Not able to understand is there a problem in Jenkins or Github settings ?
Any help/advice is appreciated.

My code is 
authemail = parsedJson.changeSets.items.authorEmail[0]

```
"author": {
        "name": "XYZ",
        "email": "XYZ@abc.com",
        "username": "xyz"
      },
      "committer": {
        "name": "GitHub Enterprise",
        "email": "noreply@server_ip"
```

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub server,for that account, might have [set a noreply email address](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-commit-email-addresses).

> If you'd like to keep your personal email address private, you can use a GitHub-provided `no-reply` email address as your commit email address.
>
> To use your `noreply` email address for commits you push from the command line, use that email address when you [set your commit email address in Git](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git).
>
> To use your noreply address for web-based Git operations, [set your commit email address on GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-on-github) and choose to **Keep my email address private**.

Comment: I rechecked my profile account and my primary email address is showing proper address. Are you referring to my user profile email address ?

Comment: @sg0133 Yes, both as recorded in the commits, and in your GitHub user profile settings, https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-on-github, with the  Keep my email address private activated.

Comment: Yes this email is ldap one , same as primary one. I don't have any private email enabled. But i am still getting this "noreply" default message in the payload.

Comment: @sg0133 If you clone that repository and do a `git log --pretty=format"%ce"`, do you see `noreply@server_ip` as committer email?

Comment: Yes i see both email address mine as well as noreply

Comment: @sg0133 As long as you see commits with "noreply", that is what you will get (through API or CLI)

Comment: One more thing other developers are also getting the same messages , the committers email shows up "noreply"

Comment: @sg0133 I meant, if a commit has been done with "noreply" as email, that is what everybody will see as email committer.